# Mixing yum repos for different OS major versions does not work

Tags: centos, yum, repository

First of all: I am well aware that in general it is a very bad idea to mix yum repos for different major OS versions.

However on CentOS 7 I need a few packages from CentOS 6. So I have added CentOS 6 repos, replacing the `$releasever` with an explicit `6.8` (again, very bad, I know).

Executing

```
yum list foobar
```

I would expect to get a list of all available versions of foobar, from CentOS 7 AND 6. However yum only shows me `el7` packages. I have verified that `foobar` is in the enabled CentOS 6 repo.

I would have expected to be able to download/install a CentOS 6 package with something like the following, which fails:

```
# yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="CentOS-6*" install foobar
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
There are no enabled repos.
 Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.
 You can enable repos with yum-config-manager --enable <repo>
```

Checking the repos as suggested:

```
# yum repolist all |grep "CentOS-6.8 - Base"
base_6/x86_64                   CentOS-6.8 - Base                 enabled: 6,696
```

Is yum doing an explicit check that the repo fits the major version? Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 2):

If you check your repo file for CentOS 6 Base in /etc/yum.repo.d/ you'll find there such strings:

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

Variable $releasever in CentOS 7 always equal seven, so if you want to install something from this repo, you should change this variable to 6.

Comment: Using '6' instead of '6.8' for $releasever seems to be correct, however, this did not help, still no centos 6 packages are downloadable.

Comment: @Isaac, try to `yum clean all` and then install package `yum --disablerepo="*CentOS-7*" install foobar`

Comment: That is what I did - I would have expected this to work, but it does not. All it offers me is the Centos 7 package.